# How does floating 2 (or more) divs work?

Tags: css, html

When I set `#p1` to `float:left`,only the content of `#p2` wraps around the floating `#p1` and not the `div#p2`.The `div#p2` seems to be present from the left edge of the browser only(as seen in Chrome developer tools).However when I set both *divs* to `float:left`, the content as well the container wraps around each other.Why is it so?

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
#p2 {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<title>Floating Divs</title>
<h1>Floating Divs</h1>
<div>
  <div id="p1">DIV</div>
  <div id="p2">DIVDIVDIV</div>
</div>
```

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
#p2 {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<title>Floating Divs</title>
<h1>Floating Divs</h1>
<div>
  <div id="p1">DIV</div>
  <div id="p2">DIVDIVDIV</div>
</div>
```

[image: Single float,#p2 is entire #p1 but content is wrapped]

[image: Both #p1 and #p2 i floated,however both container and content is wrapped]

Comment: I would just recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float . Everything is pretty well explained there. EXCEPT maybe just "it's just how it works and is meant to work" :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [precise rules for floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#float-rules) as described in the CSS 2.1 spec says in point 2:

> If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating
>   boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for
>   each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box
>   must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or
>   its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous
>   rules hold for right-floating boxes.

So `#p2` when it is floated will avoid `#p1`. When it is not floated, it will ignore the presence of `#p1`. But then, the line box contained in `#p2` avoids the floated `#p1`, causing the height of `#p2` to grow to be great enough to allow it to contain that line box.

Comment: What is the "line box" actually? Are you referring to the content?

Comment: @avistein - One line of the content. In your example `#p2` all the content fits on one line, but if you added more text, it would flow on to a second and further lines. Each line of that text is contained in a line-box. [Line box in the CSS 2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#line-box)

Comment: So the line boxes are by default floated ,right? Otherwise it would not avoid the floated `#p1`.Also are all content in html stored in line-boxes? I meant to say every thing that we write in html as content ,do all of them has a box around it?Still now I only knew that only html elements are boxes.

Comment: No line boxes are never floated. Line boxes avoid floated items according to the rules described in [9.5 Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) paragraphs 4- 6. Not everything rendered goes in a line box. For example, an img element which has been assigned `display:block` will be displayed, but not be in a line box. Floated elements themselves are not in a line box, though they may contain line boxes. Inline-level elements (`display:inline, inline-block, inline-table, inline-flex`) go in line boxes.

Comment: So every thing that we write inside div,p,span etc, all are contained in line boxes?

Comment: Only those things that are inline-level.